# GCM notifications not triggered on device

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to develop an hybrid app with Cordova using this ngcordova plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/
I was able to receive notifications and they appear if the `data` array sent includes a "message" field. From the GCM docs https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref?hl=en I read that if you had a "notification" array inside data you could customize the notification with icon, body etc... However notifications only work and show what's inside "message", all other fields in notification field are ignored. 
So what I'm asking is if the client app always has to manually show notifications on the client side. If this is the case then what is the point of the standard notification array and the requires if they're ignored?

This is the array I'm sending which triggers no notification on the device.

```
    [data] => Array
        (
            [notification] => Array
                (
                    [title] => New notification
                    [icon] => myicon
                    [body] => Geology
                )

        )

)
```

EDIT: ok so apparently `notification` must be outside of `data`!
So I changed to this:

```
Array
(
    [to] => APA91bG73Bp8AfHbOJRRkfp9axq1HgNtaG...
    [notification] => Array
        (
            [title] => New notification
            [icon] => myicon
            [body] => Geology
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [Nick] => Sandro
        )

)
```

But it still doesn't trigger anything, but it should according to the docs.

> To send notifications, set notification with the necessary predefined
>   set of key options for the user-visible part of the notification
>   message. Optionally, set data with custom key/value pairs to pass
>   additional payload to the client app. **GCM will display the
>   notification part on the client app’s behalf.** When optional data is
>   provided, it is sent to the client app once user clicks on the
>   notification and opens the client app.

Comment: do you want to set notification message and image from your message data? so need standard for message data?

Comment: I want to customize the notification box but it only appears and show a "message" field.